# File upload system, that gives the uploaded file a random name.

Tags: php, file, upload

Ok so i have a file upload system that when your file is done uploading it gives you your file link, But i want it to change the file name, and give you the new file name i would like it to be like, File_RANDOM LETTERS AND NUMBERS, AND RANDOM LENGTH BUT NOT TO LONG AND MY CAPS IS STUCK.mp4 how wolud i do this?

```
     <?php
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"];
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; 
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"];
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"];
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"];
if (!$fileTmpLoc) {
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}

if(file_exists('uploads/' . $_FILES['file1']['name'])){
    die('File with that name already exists.');
}

if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName")){

 echo "Your File Link<input value='http://testserver1234.no-ip.org/Upload-System/uploads/".  basename( $_FILES['file1']['name']).
    "' style='width: 100%'>";

} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Function to generate Random string.

```
 <?php 

function generateRandomString($length) {
    $key = '';
    $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
    }

    return $key;
}


$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"];
$fileRandomString=generateRandomString(50); // Pass Length of the String into function 
$newFileName=$fileName."-".$fileRandomString; 

?>
```